# React material-ui navigate another html page and render an initial component in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am designing a web site using material-ui (https://material-ui.com/). I have toolbar with buttons. As usual, I want to navigate another html page when I click one of the buttons and render an initial component for new html page. For example, from 'Main Page' (for now, its localhost:3000/) to 'About' page (localhost:3000/About).

[image]

I tried something similar to this,

```
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    function ListItemLink(props) {
      const { icon, primary, to } = props;
    
      const CustomLink = props => <Link to={'/About'} {...props} />;
    
      return (
          <Button component={CustomLink} /> About              
      );
    }
```

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10955 but it did not work. I searched many other methods but none of them is doing what I want. In the picture below, I have 'About' and 'News' folders under public folder. Each of them has its own index.html file. And I also have 'index.js' under src folder.

By default, nmp starts index.html under 'public' folder and execute index.js for this html file.
I want to make this scenario when I route other folders with button click.

[image]

Is there any preferrable way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading the documentation for React Router.

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

In the code below, the `Switch` component is what is used to see what should be rendered based on the `Route` components under it.

You need this switch logic setup or your buttons won't do anything.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```